# i5 7600k not running properly on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, cpu

Ubuntu version: 16.04.1 LTS

I recently upgraded some hardware but I can't get my CPU working properly. I did a benchmark and it performed worse than my 5 year old, definitely very outdated CPU.

In the additional drivers tab on the Software & Updates window it's identified as "unknown" and I can only use proprietary drivers from intel, which doesn't seem to work.

Anyone know what the issue could be and how I could go about in solving it?

Thanks.

Comment: What benchmark did you run, and why do you think it is bad?

Comment: How many cores show up in System Monitor? Occasionally an incorrect kernel parameter is set that causes only one CPU core to be activated

Comment: System profiler and benchmark: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/hardinfo/

All 4 cores show up in System Monitor.

CPU Blowfish
Old CPU 1400 MHz 2,919
New CPU 1453 MHz 1,733

Other CPU benchmarks are similar. I just realized, did I just incorrectly assume that a higher number is better?


Either way, I assume that it shouldn't be running at 1.4Ghz? The i5 is rated at 3.8Ghz.

Comment: If your i5 7600k CPU is not running to spec I'd be looking at the BIOS and mobo for potential solutions not Ubuntu.  System Settings->Details should show the processor as a 3.8 GHz x4 device.  As for the number of cores, this depends a lot on whether the OS and the apps you're running are truly multi-tasking.  For Ubuntu and *NIX generally, 4 cores will be more efficient than 2.  8 more efficient than 4 and so on.  Whether a particular benchmark actually utilizes multiple cores is another matter.

Comment: "Anyone know what the issue could be?" – Actually it would be good if you could first figure what *your* issue with the current situation is and how you'd like to change it. As your question stands we have no idea what you want to do. It's just a description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For fun I ran Blowfish from the hardinfo tool that's part of the Ubuntu standard distribution.  I assume this is the same benchmark that you are doing your testing with.

My i3-2120 3.30 GHz x 4 CPU says 1642 MHz and gives a score of 3.58.  The test runs in a couple of seconds so it's hardly an exhaustive benchmark and likely does not test using all 4 cores.

My  i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz × 8 CPU tests at 1.08 and says the CPU speed is 800 MHz.

As the results output says, a lower number in the test score indicates a better result.

Both machines are rockets in a real world computing environment.

I'd suggest that there is a problem with hardinfo's Blowfish testing capabilities and not a problem with your CPU upgrade.  Comprehensive, reliable benchmarks will take a while to run, not seconds.

As for the drivers, my machines also show as "unknown".  This fact is likely a red herring in regards to Ubuntu performing as it should with these CPUs.